# Yii functions autocompleted by IDE

Tags: yii, phpstorm

my IDE, phpStorm, won't autocomplete things like findByPk or countBySql. How to make it do that?

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/92/configuring-phpstorm-ide-for-yii/

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/news/66/yiistorm-for-phpstorm/

Answer (score 1):

PHPStorm does have support for Yii, you need to enable the [framework integration](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/framework-integration.html) in your project for that.
You can find [a guide to do that](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/92/configuring-phpstorm-ide-for-yii/) on the Yii website.

Answer (score 1):

You can try plugin for PHPStorm - YiiStorm (http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7182)

Also PHPDoc annotations helps your IDE to be more "clever". Look at this article: http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/creating-php-documentation-comments.html

Answer (score 0):

I usually use phpDoc comments for classes like this:

```
/**
 * ....
 * @method MyModel findByPk
 * @method MyModel[] findAllByAttributes
 */
class MyModel extends CActiveRecord
{
   ....
```

I did't find a better method. I create these comments only when I use some method for autocomplete in code where I use this method.